# compare two csv files, one line code fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, parsing

I have the code below (full code also is included) it is responsible for comparing 2 csv files

(I INSIST TO KEEP IT IN THE ONE LINE FORMAT IF POSSIBLE):

```
master_indices = dict(((r[0]), i) for i, r in enumerate(csv.reader(master)))
```

I need to add the statement that if the line contains '/' than enumarate and make dic

I have tried:

```
master_indices = dict(((r[0]), i) for i, r in enumerate(csv.reader(master)) if r.startswith('/') )

master_indices = dict(((r[0]), i) for i, r in enumerate(csv.reader(master)) if re.search(r'/', str(r)))

my lines looks like

1/2/3 12:02:03, aaa, 4bb5b, dddd, eeee
2 ----------> dont want this
3/4/8 1:01:54, aaa, rrrr, dddddd, fdghd
3/4/8 1:01:54  aah, 12rr, ddghddd, fdghd
3/4/8 1:01:54  agy, rr34r, ddhgdd, fdghd
47,    23,    54 ---> dont want this
```

---

FULL CODE:
import csv

```
with open('C:\\Users\\Fradad\\Desktop\\work\\New folder (2)\\NPPD-conversion\\HIS_exp_20140101\\LTA\\LTA37\\Analog_per_5_min_20140101.csv', 'r') as master:
    master_indices = dict(((r[0]), i) for i, r in enumerate(csv.reader(master)) if re.search(r'/', str(r)))


with open('C:\\Users\\Fradad\\Desktop\\work\\New folder (2)\\NPPD-conversion\\HIS_exp_20140101\\LTA\\LTA37\\Analog_exp_2014010100.csv', 'r') as hosts:
    with open('results1.csv', 'w') as results:
        reader = csv.reader(hosts)
        writer = csv.writer(results)

        writer.writerow(next(reader, []) + ['RESULTS'])

        for row in reader:
            index = master_indices.get(row[0])
            if index is not None:
                message = 'FOUND in master list (row {})'.format(index)
            else:
                message = 'NOT FOUND in master list'
            writer.writerow(row + [message])
```

Comment: could you share the errors that you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
master_indices = {r[0]:i for i,r in enumerate(csv.reader(master)) if "/" in r[0]}
```

If you want to find "/" in all the line you can do:

```
 master_indices = {r.split(",",1)[0]:i for i,r in enumerate(master) if "/" in r}
```

Comment: can you please give me one last help now i need to make that dictionary a nested one like:                                                                                                    m_l = { r[0]: {r[0] + r[1]: i}, {r[1] + r[2] + r[3]: r[6]} for i,r in enumerate(csv.reader(master)) if "/" in r[0]}

Comment: Try this: `m_l = {r[0]: {r[0] + r[1]: i, r[1] + r[2] + r[3]: r[6]} for i,r in enumerate(csv.reader(master)) if "/" in r[0]}`